# How to include monorepo packages in Cypress code coverage

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end, istanbul, nyc

I have multi packages in monorepo.

```
/pkg1
/pkg2
/pkg3
     - react-app
     - cypress
     - src
     - package.json
```

I am using `@cypress/instrument-cra` to collect coverage and it works only to cover the code inside `react-app`.

I need to go further because `react-app` is actually just a playground while the `src` has to be covered along with other packages that are used inside the `react-app`. I am importing packages as following:

```
import pkg1 from @myProject/pkg1
```

How can I use code coverage for pkg1?

I tried to config `nyc` but it didn't work

```
"nyc": {
  "all": true,
  "include": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "excludeNodeModules": false
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The structure of the monrepo is not clear. You have enabled nyc for node_modules, do you use a symlink under node_modules to enable the import of pkg1?

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker yes, i am using yarn workspace.

Comment: i think i have to override webpack config, to make node_modules/@myProject be instrumented by istanbul

Comment: Indeed, `babel-plugin-istanbul` is added to webpack config in `@cypress/instrument-cra`. If pkg1 is not React, take a look at how it's done in the source for instrument-cra.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker spent an hours without getting anywhere, then i opened an issue hoping to get any help https://github.com/cypress-io/instrument-cra/issues/172

Comment: Is there a github repo for the code? I can't understand the compilation steps for pkg1, pkg2, pkg3 and if React is the framework for all 3 pkg's or just for react-app.

Comment: Hi @HiramK.Hackenbacker. this is branch i am working on right now https://github.com/jalal246/dflex/tree/test/cy_code_cove_2

Comment: Hi, @Elisabetta. No, I haven't but resolving modules as alias could be a potential solution I am not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  cwd:"../"
}
```

By default, cypress will instrument only code residing in the react-app. So, you have to change the `cwd` to the root. Refer to this GitHub issue for more details: [nyc does not work with symlinks](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1301#issuecomment-610393242)

Answer (score 0):

Create `.nycrc` file in your root folder and:

```
{
  "all": true,
  "include": [
    "pkg1/src/**"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/test/**"
  ],
}
```